# Angular 7 : Unit test Jasmine automate window size on mobile and web

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular7

I need to write an automated test case (jasmine test) which will run in  chrome with different  resolutions for mobile and web view 
For example, it should automatically adjust the window size to 
W: 375 H: 678 when it is run in jasmine 
Unfortunately, I wasn’t able to find a solution to do this

```
it('It should set sizes according to mobile', async(() => {

     //below code is not working
     //browser.manage().window().setSize(375, 678);
     let innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
     neither it won't work following code
     window.resizeTo(375, 678);

  }));
```

Comment: How about this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204907/how-to-mock-window-screen-width-in-angular-unit-test-with-jasmine)?

Comment: it did not helped

Answer (score 9, accepted):

finally i was able to find an answer for this

it can be done by installing `npm install karma-viewport`

This will expose the global variable viewport to tests, which allows setting the dimensions of the viewport

need to config viewport sizes in karma.conf.js as follow

```
// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ["viewport"]

    // Viewport configuration
    viewport: {
      breakpoints: [
        {
          name: "mobile",
          size: {
            width: 320,
            height: 480
          }
        },
        {
          name: "tablet",
          size: {
            width: 768,
            height: 1024
          }
        },
        {
          name: "screen",
          size: {
            width: 1440,
            height: 900
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  })
}
```

then in spec file you can access the screen sizes

```
 it('should load the mobile view ', () => {
     viewport.set('mobile');
  });
```

Comment: Awesome! I finally had a reason to test viewport sizes and your question comes up first. Thank you!

Comment: did all that from Angular 9, but viewport is not recognized in my tests. Tips ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this test with karma runner? I don't think karma can control window size inside the test. You can only set window size with the launcher configuration. Otherwise, an e2e test with protractor / selenium is another solution.

Comment: I am running this test with karma runner is there any workaround for this

Answer (score 0):

@Buzz

if it's not working maybe the plugin array is missing the import.

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: [ 'viewport'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-viewport')
    ],
```